# I got whitelabel error page when i am use eureka server

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka

*i got whitelabel error page when i serch for eureka server in browser my springboot version is 2.6.3 and spring cloud version is 2023.0.0 <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
i am trying to change to spring-cloud.version i got error on dependency that is 


org.springframework.cloud
spring-cloud-dependencies
${spring-cloud.version}
pom
import


  i got error at this dependency how to solve this i added @EnableEurekaServer annotation at the first calss but i didnot got the ui of eureka server*

## this is my yml file

```
server:
  port: 8761

eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false  
    fetchRegistry: false
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  dashboard:
    path: /dashboard
  
  
spring:
  freemarker:
    prefer-file-system-access: false
    template-loader-path: classpath:/templates/
  application:
    name: eureka-server
```

## this is my pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="https://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>in.ashokit</groupId>
    <artifactId>44-SBMS-Service-Registry</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>44-SBMS-Service-Registry</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <!--  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactIda>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>-->
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>


        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

i want to get ui of eureka server in browser

Answer (score 1):

**In pom.xml** modify version of **spring-cloud.version** under properties tag, because you are using **spring boot version 2.6.3**

```
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
```